# Confused on sending messages. dialog.add()? session.send()? context.sendActivity()?

Tags: node.js, dialog, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

This is making me extremely confused and want to pull my hair out. I started with generating an echo bot from its template and it worked fine. They send messages using `turnContext.sendActivity("Some message")` via the `onTurn()` method. Sounds good... super clear.

Then I search online for how to send cards, and I see this:

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .addAttachment({ ... })
```

What is that? The echo bot template doesn't have `builder`. How do I get that? Do I need it? Where do I find how to import this `builder` thing? All I have is a `turnContext` object. Where did `session` come from?

I then see how to add authentication to my bot. I see a sample online, but now they're using `dialogs` and they're `dialog.add`ing waterfall steps. And other examples I see them using this `dialog` thing to send text responses. I thought you send text responses with `session` or `turnContext`. Now that's three different ways to send a message which I'm super confused on.

Comment: So, first, it seems like you're stumbling across some samples that use v3 (e.g. `builder`, `session`) version of the APIs and getting them confused with v4 (e.g. `turnContext`). Second, you're asking two separate questions here. Would you mind splitting this in to two separate questions? One having to do with how to work with cards and the other with how to do authentication? I'll gladly supply answers to each, but the two topics are distinct and it will be a huge confusing answer making it less helpful to people if I answer it all as one.

Comment: Actually, you answered by question. I think it was mixing between v3 and v4 like you mentioned. There's a good chance I'll have future questions, in which I'll post them in another question. Thanks @DrewMarsh.

Comment: No problem, then I'll answer as much below and if you can take a sec to upvote or mark as answer that'll be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using v4 of the framework, but stumbling across some v3 sample code. For example, the `session` no longer exists in v4. Try starting [here in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and [here for samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs) to make sure you're looking at v4 code entirely.